# unable to change sidemenu on Login and Logout - Angular Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am able to post login request, get the token and store in local storage.

I am able to Register, create new token and store it in local storage.

finally, I am able to press Logout and remove the token from local storage.

**The Issue :** When User login's, I am redirecting the user to the Dashboard page but the menu does not update because I have the code to check isLoggedin in app.component.ts file and not inside Dashboard page.

Also, When I Logout, The token is removed from localstorage and redirected to Login Page but again Menu does not update.

## login.ts

```
onSubmit(){
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: "Please wait..."
});
loader.present();
this.authService.login({email: email, password: password});
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
loader.dismiss();
}
```

## authService.ts

```
login(model: User) {
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", model)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        var tokenObj = data.text();
        var token = JSON.parse(tokenObj).success.token;
        if(token){

        localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify({token: token}));
        this.isLoggedin = true;
        }
    },
      err => {
          console.log("Error Occurred: "+err);
      });
}


logout(): void
{
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.isLoggedin = false;
}

isLoggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") == null) {
        this.isLoggedin = false;
        return this.isLoggedin;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## app.component.ts

```
rootPage: any = LoginPage;
activePage : any;
private token : string;
isLoggedin : boolean = false;

constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private menuCtrl:MenuController, public authService : AuthenticationService) {
this.initializeApp();

this.token = this.authService.getToken();
this.isLoggedin = this.authService.isLoggedIn();


this.pages = [
  { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage, icon: 'log-in'  },
  { title: 'Register', component: RegisterPage, icon: 'person-add'  },
  { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage, icon: 'stats'  },
  { title: 'Portfolio', component: ProtabsPage, icon: 'images'  },
  { title: 'Reports', component: RtabsPage, icon: 'paper'  },
  { title: 'Profile', component: PtabsPage, icon: 'person'  },
  { title: 'Customize', component: SettingsPage, icon: 'options'  },
  { title: 'Contact', component: ContactPage, icon: 'call'  },
  { title: 'Logout', component: DashboardPage, icon: 'log-out'  },
];
this.activePage = this.pages[0];

}


Logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
}
```

## app.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of pages">
<button  *ngIf="isLoggedIn && (p.title ==='Dashboard' || p.title ==='Portfolio' || p.title ==='Reports' || p.title ==='Profile' || p.title ==='Customize' || p.title ==='Contact')" padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center  [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)">
   <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
   <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
 </button>
 <button  *ngIf="isLoggedIn && (p.title ==='Logout')" padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center  [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="Logout()" menuClose>
    <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
  </button>
 <button  *ngIf="!isLoggedIn && (p.title ==='Register' || p.title ==='Login' || p.title ==='Portfolio' || p.title ==='Contact')" padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center  [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

## Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
isLoggedin : boolean = false;
.... 
this.isLoggedin = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
```

to the following:

```
get isLoggedIn(){
  return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

With the code you had, `isLoggedIn` value was 'fixed' and didn't change with any changes in other components/service. You could subscribe to it's changes in auth Service to react at any changes to logging status. Using a getter is a simple way to do the same, as get accessor get its value checked by Angular's cycle.

Comment: in app.component.ts file? I get error : `Typescript Error
';' expected`.

Comment: At which line ?

Comment: I have added the image in my question

Comment: You are missing closing } ?

Comment: I was adding it inside constructor my bad. Can you explain me what is happening in your above code?

Comment: I noticed one small issue. when I logout (go to Login Page) or Login (going to Dashboard Page) I do not see the respective button of the menu highlighted. I checked the console.log and I found out that I am not setting this.activePage to X page. but then how do I set the activePage to something when the control is in dashboard or authService.ts file. so when I login the activePage is still Login. for the active page to change I need to change this.activePage = this.pages[3] but i am unable to access this property from outside.

Comment: Probable fix: move activepage to a shared service. And set the value from each compoent on routing